# Format Matlab data to only have digits after the decimal place

Tags: matlab, number-formatting

I used dlmwrite to output some data in the following form:

```
-1.7693255974E+00,-9.7742420654E-04, 2.1528647648E-04,-1.4866241234E+00
```

What I really want is the following format:

```
-.1769325597E+00, -.9774242065E-04,  .2152864764E-04, -.1486624123E+00
```

A space is required before each number, followed by a sign, if the number is negative, and the number format is comma delimited, in exponential form to 10 significant digits.

Just in case Matlab is not able to write to this format (-.1769325597E+00), what is it called specifically so that I can research other means of solving my problem?

Comment: `-1.7693255974E+00` and  `-.1769325597E+00` is a different number, you probably want `-.1769325597E+01` instead? Then the value of the number would be unchanged.

Comment: I don't know if there's a term to designate the form you are looking for. If it helps, however, I can tell you that the 1.234e+02 is called **normalized scientific notation**. It's called normalized because the representation is arranged in order to have a single leading digit before the decimal.

Comment: Yes the new number should have been -.1769325597E+01. Apologies for the confusion, and you correction comment contributed to solving the problem of my original question. I am very grateful for your help. Thanks!        Tox.

Answer (score 0):

Although this feels morally wrong, one can use regular expressions to move the decimal point. This is what the function

```
myFormat = @(x) regexprep(sprintf('%.9e', 10*x), '(\d)\.', '\.$1');
```

does. The input value is multiplied by 10 prior to formatting, to account for the point being moved. Example: `myFormat(-pi^7)` returns `-.3020293228e+04`.

The above works for individual numbers. The following version is also able to format arrays, providing  comma separators. The second regexprep removes the trailing comma.

```
myArrayFormat = @(x) regexprep(regexprep(sprintf('%.9e, ', 10*x), '(\d)\.', '\.$1'), ', $', '');
```

Example: `myArrayFormat(1000*rand(1,5)-500)` returned

```
-.2239749230e+03, .1797026769e+03, .1550980040e+03, -.3373882648e+03, -.3810023184e+03
```

For individual numbers, `myArrayFormat` works identically to `myFormat`.

Comment: This function does exactly what I need. I still need to figure out how to get all the formatted data sets into a specified structure, but the key problem was moving the location of the decimal point. I require this format for my analysis but could not find a write function in any tool that would do this. The idea of doing it this way did not occur to me. The regexprep is quite handy! Thank you sincerely for your help.     Tox.